# Modify table constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Say I have a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE distributors ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5);
```

that needs to be modified so that zipcode length is `6`.

Do I have the drop the constraint `zipchk` first and then recreate it ?

```
ALTER TABLE distributors DROP CONSTRAINT zipchk;
ALTER TABLE distributors ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 6);
```

or is there a `MODIFY` (like) command :

```
ALTER TABLE distributors MODIFY CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 6);
```

Comment: There is no `modify` constraint (which is clearly [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)). You need to drop and re-create it.

Comment: But I think it can be done in a single statement.

Comment: There's an option `ALTER CONSTRAINT` in 9.4 but only works for foreign key constraints. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

Like [@ypercube hinted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122689/modify-table-constraint-in-postgresql#comment225045_122689), you can do it in a *single* command, which is cheaper and safer:

```
ALTER TABLE distributors
  DROP CONSTRAINT zipchk
, ADD  CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (length(zipcode) = 6);
```

`ALTER CONSTRAINT` in Postgres 9.4 or later (like you found) can only change the "deferability" of a FK constraints. So not what you are looking for. Other than that, there is no "`MODIFY`" command for constraints (referring to MySQL's `MODIFY` I assume).

Details in [the manual for `ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), like @a_horse mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that in PostgreSQL you can make DDL changes in a transaction. In your case, for example, if you change the zipcode length check from = 5 to = 6, you need to also update your old data to meet the new constraint! You can't do this unless you first drop the constraint, update the data, then add the new constraint. You do it in a transaction and everything is super-clean:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE distributors DROP CONSTRAINT zipchk;
UPDATE distributors 
   SET zipcode = zipcode || '0'
 WHERE char_length(zipcode) = 5;
ALTER TABLE distributors ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 6);
COMMIT;
```